# Помогите с алгоритмом очереди с частотой по времени

Tags: база-данных, алгоритм

В бд есть список уникальных ссылок и частотой (раз в час = 60) их парсинга (таблица watchlist),
Во второй таблице (pm) находятся результаты парсинга.
Парсер включается каждые n-минут и собирает данные только одной ссылки. (сейчас он обходит раз в 6 минут все 9 ссылок и соответственно частота обхода каждой равна ~ 1 час)
Соответственно, организована круговая очередь.
Как скрипту выбрать следующую ссылку для парсинга, учитывая частоту  обновления данных?

Comment: left join таблицы ссылок с таблицей результатов парсинга, вычисляете: "минуты(время_последного_парсинга(или 1970 год если парсинга еще не было) - текущее_время) + частота парсинга" Оставляете только записи где вычисленное значение < 0 и сортируете по этому значению. Берете первую запись полученного списка - она самая старая

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mike Ваш комментарий очень помог, реализация на postgesql:

```
SELECT watchlist.s, wl.update_rate, 
(MAX(pm.date) + 60*watchlist.update_rate - extract(epoch from now())) as dt 
FROM watchlist 
LEFT JOIN pm ON pm.s = wl.s  
GROUP BY watchlist.s, watchlist.update_rate 
ORDER BY dt ASC LIMIT 1;
```